# how to validate document paths in firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, querying

So, in my previous question, I ended up figuring out my own issue, (I would recommend taking a look at that before reading this one), but the 20 seconds of glory was cut short when I realized that the outcome was similar across all users on the app, which is what I didn't want and totally forgot about.

With the function down below, I can purchase the event and the buttons will show up for that event and go away if I cancel, and it's unique for each event, which I adore. Now, the problem with the function down below is that if I make a purchase on user1 account and the buttons show up and stay there how they're supposed to, when I log into user2 account and perhaps want to purchase that same event, the buttons are already showing up even though user2 hasn't done anything.

```
                getSchoolDocumentID { (schoolDocID) in
                if let schID = schoolDocID {
                    self.db.document("school_users/\(schID)/events/\(self.selectedEventID!)").getDocument { (documentSnapshot, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("There was an error fetching the document: \(error)")
                        } else {

                            guard let docSnap = documentSnapshot!.get("purchased") else {
                                return
                            }
                            if docSnap as! Bool == true {
                                self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
                                self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
                                self.creditCard.isHidden = true
                                self.purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = true

                            } else {
                                self.creditCard.isHidden = false
                                self.purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

So i tried to solve the problem on my own but ran into a roadblock. I tried to make a subcollection of `events_bought` when users purchase an event and have the details stored in fields that I can call later on in a query. This was something I thought I could use to make the  purchases unique amongst all users.

The function below looks through `events_bought` subcollection and pulls up a field and matches it with a piece of data on the displayedVC, the issue is if the event hasn't been purchased and I go on it with that user, it crashes and says how the document reference path has the wrong number of segments which I don't get because it's the same as the function above, so I realized that the path wouldn't exist and tried to figure out ways to validate the path and came up with the function down below.

```
getEventsBoughtEventID { (eventBought) in
        if let idOfEventBought = eventBought {
            
            let docPath = self.db.document("student_users/\(self.user?.uid)/events_bought/\(idOfEventBought)")
            
            if docPath.path.isEmpty {
                self.creditCard.isHidden = false
                self.purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = false
            } else {
                self.db.document("student_users/\(self.user?.uid)/events_bought/\(idOfEventBought)").getDocument { (documentSnapshot, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("There was an error trying to fetch this document: \(error)")
                    } else {
                        guard let docSnapEventName = documentSnapshot!.get("event_name") else {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        if docSnapEventName as! String == self.selectedEventName! {
                            self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
                            self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
                            self.creditCard.isHidden = true
                            self.purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I wasn't really sure if it would work or not so I tried my luck, but I still end up getting the same document reference errors. If anyone can figure out how I can validate a document path and use logic to make certain things happen, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finally figured out how to come about doing this. It was a 4 hour grind and struggle but i got it, with a few bugs of course. So i found out the reason my app crashed was not just because of the path segments, but cause of the fact that the `idOfEventBought` didn't exist for some events because those events weren't purchased yet and that there was no subcollection called `events_bought` even created yet.

Firstly, I added a test document in a subcollection called `events_bought` when a user signs up, which makes sense because it would have to be made eventually anyways.

```
 db.document("student_users/\(result?.user.uid)/events_bought/test_document").setData(["test": "test"])
```

This line of code allowed me to come up with my next method, that can verify if an event was bought or not.

```
func checkIfUserMadePurchase(shouldBeginQuery: Bool) -> Bool {
    if shouldBeginQuery == true {
        
        getEventsBoughtEventID { (eventBought) in
            if let idOfEventBought = eventBought {

                self.docListener = self.db.document("student_users/\(self.user?.uid)/events_bought/\(idOfEventBought)").addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { (documentSnapshot, error) in

                    if let documentSnapshot = documentSnapshot {

                        if documentSnapshot.exists {
                            self.creditCard.isHidden = true
                            self.purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = true
                            self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
                            self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         
        }
        return true
    
 } else {
    creditCard.isHidden = false
    purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = false
    viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
    cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
    return false
    }
}
```

I used this method to verify if the event has been purchased yet, and if it hasn't show the right buttons.

I then call it in the process of when the purchase button in my `UIAlertController` is pressed.

```
       self.checkIfUserMadePurchase(shouldBeginQuery: true)
```

Lastly, I create a function that uses logic to verify is the event has been purchased, and if it has been purchased, do something specific. I then call this function in the `viewDidLoad()` , `viewWillAppear()`, and `viewWillDisappear()`.

```
func purchasedStatusVerification() {
    db.collection("student_users/\(user?.uid)/events_bought").whereField("event_name", isEqualTo: self.selectedEventName!).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
            if querySnapshot.isEmpty {
                self.checkIfUserMadePurchase(shouldBeginQuery: false)
            } else {
                self.checkIfUserMadePurchase(shouldBeginQuery: true)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

With all this in place, my app runs how i want to, I can successfully purchase an event and it won't show up in another users account. There are a few bugs like when a new event is created, the wrong and the right buttons are all displayed, but the wrong buttons go away after logging in and out. Also, the `isHidden()` method moves pretty slow, when i load the vc and the event has a status of purchased, the `purchaseTicketButton` is there for a split second, then disappears, which is quite annoying. All in all, I figured it out, and will try to improve it near production time.

Comment: You're going to want to fix this `user?.uid` as if the user is nil, your app will crash; protect your code by safely unwrapping optionals. A second issue is this statement `return true` will execute *before the code within the firebase closure* which means it will pretty much return true every time. Firebase is asynchronous and code is faster than the internet - that's going to cause long term, intermittent issues. Lastly, you've got code to see if the event has been purchased but that's based on if the event exists. Seems that if it doesn't exist then it was obviously not purchased.

Comment: Great. So instead of just pointing out issues alone, can you maybe add an answer and explain what I need to do and where in my code, so I don't have to possibly run into these issues in the future? Also, the user literally can't be nil, once you sign up, the path is created, and it's created with the optional user id, it is impossible to get into the app without authentication and actually creating an account, so I don't get how the user can be nil. @Jay

Comment: A user could be nil for a number of reasons. See the note [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). Posting an additional answer would be a duplicate of a lot of other answers. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60272535/i-keep-getting-a-sigabrt-error-when-trying-to-read-my-firebase-database-and-crea/60383635#60383635) or search for [Firebase Async](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5DFirebase+is+asynchronous) for a bunch of examples. The other issue was just a logic thing which you can work though.

Comment: Good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @llompalles, and thanks just did it now.

Answer (score 0):

In your document path `"student_users/\(self.user?.uid)/events_bought/\(idOfEventBought)"` you use `self.user?`.
`?` will produce
`student_users/Optional(uid)/events_bought` string,
but not
`student_users/uid/events_bought` string.
Use `self.user!` or `if let user = self.user {`

Comment: I have to or else the path will be incorrect and the code will crash. I don't think the issue is within the path, the path works fine.  @Aznix

Comment: So with `\(self.user?.uid)` you path will be incorrect

Comment: No, it's correct with that. Look at the path in my Firestore database:

`/student_users/Optional("UhRGfXkk3cbCQt02S6q54B0uydE3")/events_bought/cg3bQv3hRoucAnnuDEBV`. @Aznix

Comment: True path can be `/student_users/UhRGfXkk3cbCQt02S6q54B0uydE3/events_bought/cg3bQv3hRoucAnnuDEBV`. `Optional` is unwanted in path

Comment: Brother, I've used optionals in my paths in about 20 Firestore query calls by now and they all work perfect. @Aznix