# Get reference to data stored in Firestore database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a problem getting reference to data i stored in a collection, in firebase firestore.
I am trying to retrieve the users data from firebase and then save their posts with this data in the realtime database.

I have store the data in variables that are called Tokens so that i get get access to the value in another function. I get an error saying that a fatal error occurs and that a value of nil was unexpectedly returned.

```
func setUpPosts() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let database = Firestore.firestore()

    // get data from firestore
    let docRef = database.collection("users")
    docRef.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: true).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let fullnametext = document["fullname"] as? String
                self.fullnameToken = fullnametext
                let degreetext = document["degree"] as? String
                self.degreeToken = degreetext
                let universitytext = document["university"] as? String
                self.universityToken = universitytext
            }
        }
    }
    
    let postObject = ["author": ["uid": uid, "fullname": fullnameToken, "degree": degreeToken, "university": universityToken], "text": PostTextField.text, "timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"]] as [String: Any]
}
```

Comment: You are not showing all relevant lines of code.  Where do self.fullnameToken, self.degreeToken, self.universityToken come from?  Search for firestore + asynchronous.

Comment: The code was not formatted so the issue was not clear from the question. I have formatted it and removed the trailing and extra }) as that was complicating the issue. Now that it's formatted it's clear that you're attempting to populate `postObject` with data which is not available yet. Firebase calls are asynchronous and it takes time for data to return from the server. Because of that, Firebase data is only valid within the closure and any code *following* the closure, like `let postObject = ["author": ["uid": uid...` will execute *before* the code in the closure.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025373/read-data-firebase-assign-value/56062986#56062986) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60272535/i-keep-getting-a-sigabrt-error-when-trying-to-read-my-firebase-database-and-crea/60383635#60383635) and maybe just a search here on SO for [Firebase Asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bswift%5Dfirebase+asynchronous) as @ElTomato suggested.

Comment: Ah I understand! I have moved postObject code inside the closure and it works now, thanks Jay!

Comment: If there is a solution to this issue, someone (even OP) should post it as an answer, I think